# Why does replacing the apple emoji replace all fruit emojies?

Tags: javascript, replace, unicode, v8, emoji

I was reading [this](https://v8.dev/features/string-replaceall) V8 blog post about the new `String.prototype.replaceAll` where they show this example:

```js
console.log(
  ''.replace(//g, '')
)
```

Why are all fruits being replaced instead of just the green apple?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see just the Apple being replaced.

Comment: It's only replacing the apples for me too. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Brave `v1.11.104` Chromium `84.0.4147.105` 64bit on Windows 10.

Comment: Weird I just installed brave and it is showing as desired, could you share an screenshot ?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Odd that only the last emoji in the code block doesn't render for you. Could be some sort of bug related to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a question of which fonts you have installed on your system.

When I first saw this question, I only saw square boxes, before and after replacing. Installing the "Noto Emoji" font and restarting my browser fixed it for me: now I see fruits, including a tomato to replace the apple with.

JavaScript (and V8) does what you'd expect; you just need to get your system to render the emoji for you correctly.

Comment: What's weird though is that I can see (some of) the emojis before replacing, but none of them afterwards, even the ones that have not changed.